# Sortabletable: mark few rows on start

Tags: javascript, php, sorting

I'm using this [sortabletable script](http://tablefilter.free.fr). I need to mark few rows on start - I found these properties
`...select_row_at_start: true,
row_index_at_start: 3,...`

which almost do what I need but I want to add few more rows and I can't find a way.

Comment: what criteria do the entries you are wanting to select have to meet? are you just trying to select the first few rows in the table?

Comment: If I manage to select more than one, i will manage to the rest on my own. I can generate a list with the row numbers or something like that.

Comment: @Crackers do you have any ideas?